# Filtering Output of Nested Function Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to use this filter function: `=FILTER(I2:I65, NOT(COUNTIF(Q2:Q4, I2:I65)))` to filter the output of `={"getSeries";UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(LEFT(L2:L194, SEARCH("-",L2:L194)-1),L2:L194)))}` Both functions work perfectly independently but I was wondering if it's possible to incorporate the filter into the array function. That way it outputs all of the values that do not equal the values in Q2:Q4.

Comment: yes it's possible, but please share a simple sample sheet (editable) so ideas can be tested and demo'd

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Demo: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D2sIyCCWpnJwTNjwQ_Bt4GPlT2jG3G5mHQ897YYuTW8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the demo spreadsheet that you have shared, try using this formula in say G1 `=QUERY(A1:A29, "Select A where not A contains '"&TEXTJOIN("' and not A contains '", TRUE, E2:E)&"'", 1)`

Comment: that would work except I need all of the numbers to the left of the "-" in the middle of the number.

Comment: You can then use the same logic that you were using in your original formula to extract text.

=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(LEFT(QUERY(A1:A29, "Select A where not A contains '"&TEXTJOIN("' and not A contains '", TRUE, E2:E)&"'", 1), SEARCH("-",QUERY(A1:A29, "Select A where not A contains '"&TEXTJOIN("' and not A contains '", TRUE, E2:E)&"'", 1))-1),QUERY(A1:A29, "Select A where not A contains '"&TEXTJOIN("' and not A contains '", TRUE, E2:E)&"'", 1)))